# How to drop rows that do not meet multiple conditions python

Tags: pandas, filter

I have a large df of the following structure:

```
Grade   Price   Group
A   2   apple
A   10  apple
A   9   apple
A   10  apple
B   8   apple
B   7   apple
B   6   apple
B   10  apple
A   12  berry
A   11  berry
A   11  berry
A   12  berry
A   10  berry
B   9   berry
B   9   berry
B   10  berry
B   11  berry
```

I need to filter the df based on the below conditions for each `Group`. If it is an apple then the Grades should be within the below limit or else exclude those which violate for this `Group`. It has to check for each unique `Group` variable and check the price is in range of the corresponding grades.

```
apple
A   9-10
B   7-8

berry
A   11-12
B   9-10
```

The output df should then be having those only which meet the criteria.

```
Grade   Price   Group
A   10  apple
A   9   apple
A   10  apple
B   8   apple
B   7   apple
A   12  berry
A   11  berry
A   11  berry
A   12  berry
B   9   berry
B   9   berry
B   10  berry
```

I currently filter the dataframe that meet each condition and concatenate the resulting dataframes.

```
a = df[(df['Group'] == 'apple') & (df['Grade'] == 'A') & (df['Price'].between(9, 10))]

b = df[(df['Group'] == 'apple') & (df['Grade'] == 'B') & (df['Price'].between(7, 8))]

res = pd.concat([a,b])
```

and this is not optimal to write to multiple data frames for each condition.

Any efficient solution that excludes those that do not meet the criteria would be helpful.

Comment: your inputs are unclear, please provide code to set up all constructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dataframe that OP shares in the question is `df1` and one wants to create a new dataframe, `df2`, the following filter would do the work

```
df2 = df1[(df1['Group'] == 'apple') & ((df1['Grade'] == 'A') & (df1['Price'].between(9, 10)) | (df1['Grade'] == 'B') & (df1['Price'].between(7, 8))) | (df1['Group'] == 'berry') & ((df1['Grade'] == 'A') & (df1['Price'].between(11, 12)) | (df1['Grade'] == 'B') & (df1['Price'].between(9, 10)))]

[Out]:
   Grade  Price  Group
1      A     10  apple
2      A      9  apple
3      A     10  apple
4      B      8  apple
5      B      7  apple
8      A     12  berry
9      A     11  berry
10     A     11  berry
11     A     12  berry
13     B      9  berry
14     B      9  berry
15     B     10  berry
```

---

As per [OP's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73810978/how-to-drop-rows-that-do-not-meet-multiple-conditions-python/73811014?noredirect=1#comment130333311_73811014), one can use the following function

```
def filter_df(df, groups, prices):

    # Create a list of conditions
    conditions = []

    # For each group
    for group in groups:

        # For each grade
        for grade in prices[group].keys():

            # Create a condition
            condition = (df['Group'] == group) & (df['Grade'] == grade) & (df['Price'].between(prices[group][grade][0], prices[group][grade][1]))

            # Append the condition to the list of conditions
            conditions.append(condition)

    # Filter the dataframe
    df = df[np.any(conditions, axis=0)]

    # Return the filtered dataframe
    return df
```

And apply it for OP's use case as follows (basically one will have to pass a list with all the groups, and a dictionary with the group, grades, and price range)

```
df3 = filter_df(df1, ['apple', 'berry'], {'apple':{'A':[9, 10], 'B':[7, 8]}, 'berry':{'A':[11, 12], 'B':[9, 10]}})

[Out]:
   Grade  Price  Group
1      A     10  apple
2      A      9  apple
3      A     10  apple
4      B      8  apple
5      B      7  apple
8      A     12  berry
9      A     11  berry
10     A     11  berry
11     A     12  berry
13     B      9  berry
14     B      9  berry
15     B     10  berry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary for your condition and use `apply`:

```
dct = {'apple': {'A': range(9, 11), 'B': range(7, 9)}, \
       'berry': {'A': range(11, 13), 'B': range(9, 11)}}
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.Price in dct[x.Group][x.Grade] , axis=1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

`apples = [apple for apple in myList if apple.Price == 'apple']`

Something along this would work, not tested, but list comprehension works well for this problem.